# Need a ARM template to create a VM, using latest azure storage VHD URI

Tags: azure

use case: Storage account will be there with a container/blob created which will have some 120gb OS disk VHD URI. Now there will be arm template for creating VM. this arm template should work in such a way that it should take latest VHD URI from storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/
You can find more than a 1000 quick-start ARM templates, choose the one that's closer to what you're looking for, make the appropriate edits and you're fine to go.